# What's the best way to use the SO/SF/SU wiki option?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, usability

Say I have this great documentation and I want to upload it somewhere for others to have the opportunity to see it.  I could just document it on my personal blog, or google site... but what if I'd like SO/SF/SU users to comment on it, enhance the research/documentation, collaborate and share ideas?  What if I'd like to link to other people's posts/documentations in a centralized and familiar form?

I thought that was the purpose of the 'wiki' option, but maybe I'm completely wrong.  If I'm not wrong, I think this needs to:

- **A) Be communicated/advertised more clearly,**

or/and

- **B) Be re-organized in a way that it lends itself for better usability.**

Coming from this answer to a Server Fault question: "[Where can I document useful things to know as a Mac sysadmin?](https://serverfault.com/questions/53831/where-can-i-document-useful-things-to-know-as-a-mac-sysadmin/53833#53833)"

Comment: +1 for an excellent question ;)

Answer (score 2):

That **should** be the purpose of the wiki option, and I'd go with A) **and** B). The nature of the site (and the attitudes of a lot of members) will probably prevent anything that isn't a cut-and-dried question and answer, though. I'd like to find some sort of alternative somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Post a question that your documentation answers. Make it a good one. And make sure your documentation is a good answer before you post it as one...

Comment: +1 This is how people look for info, so that's a great way to make it retrievable. I would not be as engaged if this were just text.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think SO is geared towards documentation type posts. The main goal is to answer specific issues dealing with computers, programming, or sysadmin tasks. There are some examples where list posts have done well, but there's many more where they've been massively down voted and closed.

Sticking with SO as an example, I don't think it was ever intended to be a site to *learn* how to program, it's a resource for you to use when you're stuck with your current knowledge.

Personally I feel like great documentation can come in handy, but it's not really something I want to see on the SO family sites. If you still insist on posting it, make sure it's focused;  "How to use *this* function in *this* language", not "How Classes work in Java".